# how to send purchase request to google analytics via Analytics.js with "ga" command?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, analytics.js

Okay lets start
I did include small script in my "head" template at the all pages

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,"script","https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js","ga");

    ga("create", "' . $this->getTrackId() . '", "auto");

    ga("require", "ec");

    ga("send", "pageview");        
    </script>
```

and other scripts:

> for view product detail

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ga("ec:addProduct", {               // Provide product details in a productFieldObject.
        "id":"' . $post_id . '",        // Product ID (string).
        "name":"' . $title . '",        // Product name (string).
        "category":"' . $categories . '"       // Product category (string).
    });

    ga("ec:setAction","click", {       // click action.
        "list":"' . $categories . '"          // Product list (string).
    });
    ga("send", "pageview"); 
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ga("ec:addProduct", {
      "id": "' . $post_id . '",
      "name": "' . $title . '",
      "category": "' . $categories . '"
    });
    ga("ec:setAction", "detail");
    ga("send", "pageview"); 
    </script>
```

> for purchase

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        ga("ec:addProduct", {               
            "id": "'.$product_id_arr.'",                   
            "name": "'.$name.'", 
            "variant": "'.$variant.'",              
            "price": "'.$subtotal.'",                
            "quantity": "'.$qty.'"                    
            });

        ga("ec:setAction", "purchase", {         
        "id": "'.$trans.'"                       
        });
        ga("send", "pageview");  
        </script>
```

> and other classic analytics.js functions

each code includes ga ("send", "pageview"); line, but because of this, pageview statistics increases by several times and is incorrect. Without this line, data such as "purchase" stop being sent. What do i do?

I need to make the number of page views correct, while other data should also be sent, what are the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have "send" pageview for all your pages in the head, what you can do is [use "events"](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) for the rest. This is assuming product detail and product purchase are all events happening on the same page.

Example, instead of sending a pageview for product detail, you can send an event:

```
  ga('send', 'event', 'product', 'view-detail', 'PRODID000111');
```

for purchase:

```
  ga('send', 'event', 'product', 'purchase', 'PRODID000111');
```

the pattern is

```
  ga('send', 'event', {EVENT CATEGORY}, {EVENT ACTION}, {EVENT LABEL});
```